# strptime returning NA

Tags: r, strptime

I am getting NA value for my date string using strptime in R.
I looked at the various answers, but it didn't work.
Here is my code

```
startDate=strptime("Wed May 25 01:51:32 UTC 2016", format="%a %B %d %H:%m:%S %Z %Y", tz="UTC")
print(startDate)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For those voting to close as a "simple typographical error", note that it still doesn't work if you change `%H:%m:%S` to `%H:%M:%S` because `%Z` causes an error on input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"%H:%m:%S"` should be `"%H:%M:%S"`. Once you change that, you'll get an error because `%Z` is not valid for input.

If all the datetime strings have UTC timezone, this will work:

```
R> strptime("Wed May 25 01:51:32 UTC 2016", "%a %B %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y", "UTC")
[1] "2016-05-25 01:51:32 UTC"
```

If not, then you can extract the year and prepend it to the string, because `strptime` will ignore all characters after those specified by the format string.

```
R> dts <- "Wed May 25 01:51:32 UTC 2016"
R> dtf <- "%Y %a %B %d %H:%M:%S"
R> strptime(paste(substring(dts, nchar(dts)-3), dts), dtf, "UTC")
[1] "2016-05-25 01:51:32 UTC"
```